# How to disable avahi-daemon without uninstalling it

Tags: debian, kali-linux, avahi

I am running Kali 2.0 64-bit, and I recently noticed that avahi-daemon is starting at boot time, listening on several udp ports.

How do I disable it completely, without purging the package itself?

I have tried 
    `sudo rcconf --off avahi-daemon`

But there is a warning:
    **Service 'avahi-daemon' is already off. Skipping...**

I then tried
    `sudo update-rc.d -f avahi-daemon remove`

It doesn't produce any errors, nor warnings, but avahi-daemon still persists at boot time.

I then tried editing the **/etc/default/avahi-daemon** file by adding `AVAHI_DAEMON_START = 0`

But that doesn't work either.

I finally used the UPSTART manual override -->> `echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/avahi-daemon.override`

And still no go.

Please help,

I am at my wits's end!

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon` to disable boot time startup.

A few other options are `systemctl list-units` for a list of all known units, `systemctl enable` to enable boot time startup, `systemctl start` to start the service from terminal, but not enable boot time loading and `systemctl stop` to stop a service which has been started. `man systemctl` and `man systemd` will provide complete set of options.

Most (not all though) modern Linux distributions have switched or are switching to systemd from the traditional SysV init scripts. Also, http://blog.jorgenschaefer.de/2014/07/why-systemd.html covers some of the basics of systemd.

Comment: somehow, avahi-daemon wont stop even after systemctl stop avahi-daemon. The message is  Warning: Stopping avahi-daemon.service, but it can still be activated by:  avahi-daemon.socket. And when I see the status it restarts automatically. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: A systemd `.socket` unit is designed to auto-start a service whenever something else needs it. This need is detected by a connection to an IPC or network socket, which systemd then passes on to the service, similar to inetd. If you don't want this behavior, you should disable the socket unit too: `systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket`. Alternatively, `systemctl mask avahi-daemon.service` explicitly blocks the service from starting for any reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, after some experimentation, I've found the only way to get avahi-daemon to stop -- even momentarily -- is to disable it completely using [@Daniel's answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432821/41735). The only thing I would add is the `--now` flag to the `disable` command, which both _stops and disables_ the unit, rather than just keeping it from starting on boot: `sudo systemctl disable --now avahi-daemon.socket && sudo systemctl disable --now avahi-daemon.service`

Answer (score 10):

My solution was to edit **/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf** and make the following change:

`use-ipv4=no
use-ipv6=no`

Then do a

`root@magrf# service avahi-daemon restart`

Verify that avahi daemon is stopped:

`root@magrf#  ps -ef | grep avahi
root      8311  8220  0 17:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep avahi
root@magrf#`

As you can see, avahi processes are not running.
If restart fails, try an explicit

`root@magrf# service avahi-daemon stop
root@magrf# service avahi-deamon start`

Restart is important so avahi could re-read configuration and shutdown service processes. Then it had performed a graceful exit.

Comment: This is genius! avahi has been a pita for me for years, I used to chmod -x the binary and this used to work.. but nowadays that makes other gnome features hang waiting for an answer from this pinnacle of despair.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following to stop the service, avoid restart on the next boot and
prevent apps that tickle the socket from restarting it.

```
sudo systemctl mask avahi-daemon
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon
sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon
```

Comment: This is the answer. Not only does it work, but it seems like intended operation instead of a hack. Afterwards, `systemctl status avahi-daemon.service` responds with "Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit avahi-daemon.service is masked.) Active: inactive (dead)"

Comment: I did not notice any problems at first, but it seems like document scan with `xsane` needs it for some reason

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it with:

```
systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket
```

And

```
systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service
```

Comment: This didn't prevent Avahi from becoming active again after a reboot. Raspberry Pi OS (Debian-based) 2022-04-04.

Comment: Use "mask" to completely disable a service.